# Windows 10 Wi-Fi hotspot on/off

Tags: wireless-networking, scheduled-tasks, mobile-hotspot

I use my Wi-Fi mobile hotspot frequently. Is it possible to set it up to turn on/off at set times of day? Is it possible to set it to turn on when specified Wi-Fi devices, such as phones or laptops, come into range? How about both options? Any will do…

Answer (score 1):

You can enable / disable the Windows 10 Hotspot with NETSH.

[Windows 10 Hotspot](https://winaero.com/how-to-enable-mobile-hotspot-in-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Turn%20on%20or%20off%20Mobile%20Hotspot%20in%20the%20command%20prompt,wlan%20set%20hostednetwork%20mode%3Ddisallow%20.)

> Open a command prompt as Administrator. Type the following command to
> turn on the mobile hotspot. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow` .
> This command disables the hotspot: `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow`

Once you have tested this, you can use Task Scheduler to set the task as required. You may need more than one task.

You can also set up Desktop shortcuts to run the NETSH easily on demand.